# AJax Submit onclick Font Awesome Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to display a simple rating option on a website, a thumbs up & down that when clicked will send the response to my external URL.

The site will be displayed on mobile devices as well as desktops (that's why i'm using `touchstart` and `click`).

I need to post the following values to my external URL;

- date
- time
- feedback (good / bad)

I'm successfully receive the date and time, but not feedback type. Looking at the console I can see the following;

[image]

My code is as follows;

**HTML**

```
<form id="kioskFeedback">
    <a href="#" id="feedbackGood" name="Feedback" value="GOOD"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-4x"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="feedbackBad" name="Feedback" value="BAD"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-4x"></i></a>
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getFullYear();
        var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
        $("#kioskFeedback").on("touchstart, click", function(e) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "my external url here",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData + '&Date=' + date + '&Time=' + time
            });
            .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('success');
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: your form doesn't contain any form elements, and even if hyperlinks counted as form elements, you've got two with the same name, which will conflict. I think you need to handle these pictures being clicked on and use that to populate a hidden field within your form with the selected value. Also, better to handle the "submit" event of the form instead of click or touch events.

Comment: This form doesn't have any field. Use radio buttons in this form and serialize it.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @ADyson's comment, look at the docs for `$.serialize()` http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

---

To Make what you have work...

Change this `var serializedData = $(this).serialize();`

to this `var serializedData = $(this).attr('value');`

That should get you started. Once you read the documentation and understand that `<a></a>` elements are not form elements and the `$.serialize()` method will not return the expected results you may want to go back and update the rest of the click handler to use a different variable name like so,

```
    $("#kioskFeedback a").on("touchstart, click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var feedbackVal = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: "my external url here",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                // If the script is expecting "Feedback" swap in place of "value"
                value: feedbackVal,
                Date: date,
                Time: time
            }
        });
        .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success');
        });
    });
```

Also you should change `event.preventDefault();` to `e.preventDefault()` seeing that your event information is being passed as `e` and not `event`.

Your target needs to get updated also, so adding an `a` to `$("#kioskFeedback")`
like this `$("#kioskFeedback a")` will shrink the scope to the link element. Allowing you to get the attribute value.

I am also attaching a working fiddle.

```js
$("#kioskFeedback a").on("touchstart, click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var feedbackVal = $(this).attr('value');
  console.log(feedbackVal);
  /* $.ajax({
      url: "my external url here",
      type: "post",
      data: {
          // If the script is expecting "Feedback" swap in place of "value"
          value: feedbackVal,
          Date: date,
          Time: time
      }
  });
  .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log('success');
  }); */
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="kioskFeedback">
  <a href="#" id="feedbackGood" name="Feedback" value="GOOD"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-4x"></i></a>
  <a href="#" id="feedbackBad" name="Feedback" value="BAD"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-4x"></i></a>
</form>
```

Comment: `$(this).val()` called on the form won't contain any data either

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the very detailed explanation, it helped me a lot :)